# How to get the server IP address from its response with Volley?

Tags: android, kotlin, web-services, android-volley

Is there any way to get the server IP address from its response?

```
val stringRequest = StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,

    { response ->
        // How can I get the server IP address from here?
    },

    { error ->

    })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only solution I found is to ask the server to include its IP address inside the response.